# SML: I want to go through a list and return the number of elements that return true when inputted into a given function

Tags: list, sml, ml

The question might sound confusing but basically 
I want to make a function that takes in a list and another function. Now going through that list I want to get the count of elements that return true when inputted into this parameter function. Im new to sml so my mistake was that I intended to add a count to a helper function and increment that alongside If statements but I learned soon enough that you can't really increment values in ml. Can someone please explain the more sml way of doing this? I'm just looking to understand what I'm missing.

```
fun helper f nil counter = false
  | helper f xs 1 = true
  | helper f (x::xs) counter = 
    if (f x) = true then
      counter = counter + 1
    else
      counter = counter + 0


fun numberExisting f alist = (helper f alist 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should not return a boolean, so neither should your helper.
"Incrementing" is also a concept that doesn't make much sense in a language without mutation.
(`counter = counter + 1`is a comparison that will never be true.)

You don't need the helper, but you need to think recursively:

- If the list is empty, the result is zero.
- If the list is not empty:

  - If the given predicate is true for the head of the list, the result is one more than the result of recursing over the tail of the list.
  - If the given predicate is false for the head of the list, the result is the same as the result of recursing over the tail of the list.

In ML:

```
fun numberExisting _ [] = 0
  | numberExisting f (x::xs) = if f x 
                               then 1 + numberExisting f xs
                               else numberExisting f xs
```

Comment: Thank you, it took me a while to get to this solution myself but it makes much more sense. I'll continue practicing to get a better understanding on ml.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, we can use a left fold to compute this, as the fold generalizes the recursion.

```
fun count f lst = 
  foldl (fn (x, i) => if f x then i+1 else i) 0 lst
```

It may help in understanding this to see `foldl` implemented.

```
fun foldl _ i [] = i
  | foldl f i (x::xs) = foldl f (f (x, i)) xs
```